# I can't insert to my database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i can't insert to my database whats is my problem?

it's bowling game and i have two tables with name "Player" and "Result"

view

```
<%= form_for player_new_path(@player) do |f|%>
<div class="text_field">
    <p>
    <%= f.label "Spelare namn" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p> 
    <%= f.submit "Lägg till en spelare"%>
    </p>
</div>
```

```
Controller
 def create
   @player = Player.new(params[:players])

  if @player.save
    redirect_to players_new_path
   else
  render :action => "new"
end        

end
```

---

Not work :/
my model:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base # attr_accessible :title, :body 
    belongs_to :result 
end
```

and my migrations:

```
class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change 
        create_table :players do |t|
        t.string "name"
        t.references :results 
        t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: BTW, your path helpers are a little confusing. Rails convention would be 'new_player_path'. Also, you can just pass your @player to the form_for helper and it'll choose the url based on whether or not the object is persisted.

Answer (score 3):

Check your params hash. I bet the key isn't 'players', it's probably 'player'.

Comment: Not work :/

my model

     class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
        # attr_accessible :title, :body
         belongs_to :result
      end

and my migrations: 

   class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :players do |t|
     t.string "name"
     t.references :results
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

`@player = Player.new(params[:players])` should probably be `@player = Player.new(params[:player])` (You are getting a single player as a param)

Otherwise, what error are you getting